# Метод matches.(String regex)

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Мне нужно запретить использование цифр, пробелов и разных символов (?, &, %, и т.д.) в строке. Вот так все работает

```
if(!name.matches("[a-z][A-Z]")) /*...*/
```

Если записать вот так, не работает

```
if(name.matches("\\W"))
```

Пробовал еще несколько вариантов тоже не работало. Вот мне и интересно, что я упускаю? Почему один вариант работает, а другой нет? И еще, можно мне как-то узнать индекс "запрещенного" символа и вывести его? Типо IllegalCharacter: &

Comment: Укажите что именно не работает и на каких значениях `name`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`String.matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) проверяет удовлетворяет ли строка целиком заданному регулярному выражению.

Т.о. `name.matches("[a-z][A-Z]")` вернет `true` только если `name` удовлетворяет выражению `[a-z][A-Z]`, т.е. состоящих из одной строчной буквы (`a-z`) и одной прописной (`A-Z`). Например, для строк: `aB`, `zA`. Для всех остальных вернется `false`.

Условие же `name.matches("\\W")` выполнится только для строк состоящих из одного символа, который не является буквой латинского алфавита или цифрой (`\W`). Например для строк: `[`, `!`, `$`.

Если хотите проверить, что в строке содержатся только символы латинского алфавита и цифры воспользуйтесь выражением: `\\w+` (эквивалентно `[a-zA-Z0-9]+`)

```
if(name.matches("\\w+")) {
    //в строке только цифры и латинские буквы
}
```

> И еще, можно мне как-то узнать индекс "запрещенного" символа и вывести его?

Есть разные способы:

- использовать [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

  ```
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\W");
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(name);
  //если найден запрещенный символ
  if (matcher.find()) {
      //берем первое его вхождение
      int index = matcher.start();
  } else {
      //запрещенных символов нет 
  }
  ```
- перебирать символы самому (возможно, код будет легче читать/редактировать)

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < name.length(); i++) {
      char ch = name.charAt(i);
      if (!isValid(ch)) {
          int index = i;
      }
  }

  boolean isValid(char ch) {
      return (ch >= '0' && ch <= '9') || (ch >= 'a' && ch <= 'z') || (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z');
  }
  ```
- использовать [`String.split`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)), чтобы разбить строку по запрещенным символам

  ```
  String[] subs = name.split("\\W", -1);
  if (subs.length == 1) {
      //запрещенных символов нет
  } else if (subs.length > 1) {
      //запрещенные символы есть
      int index = subs[0].length();
  } else {
      //пустая строка
  }
  ```

Comment: А можете подсказать, как найти те символы, которые не удовлетворяют условию?

Comment: Что для строки denys, что для de$nys метод name.matches("\\W+") возвращает false. Как быть?

Comment: @ДенисСавенко `name.matches("\\W+")` будет true для непустой строки сплошь состоящей из нецифровых, небуквенных символов, например, для `$$$$[[[]]`. Я дополнил ответ насчет поиска позиции